# How to fix poetry virtual environment

Tags: python, batch-file, python-poetry

I'm trying to do a task where I have to run poetry virtual environments and execute some code that has to run its virtual environment and execute its code in it. But there is a problem, the virtual environment remains the same.

run.bat (C:\User\Documents\prj2)

```bash
cd path/to/prj2
poetry install
poetry show -v
```

runner.py

```py
import subprocess

import typer

def typer_main(path_to_bath: str = typer.Argument('test')):
    subprocess.run(path_to_bath)


def script_main():
    """Точка входа для запуска скрипта."""
    typer.run(typer_main)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    script_main()
```

start.bat

```bash
poetry install
poetry run python runner.py ./path/to/prj2/run.bat
poetry show -v
```

Run this project

```bash
./start.bat
```

OUTPUT

```
(project1-py3.10) PS C:\Users\User\Documents\project1>./start.bat

(project1-py3.10) PS C:\Users\User\Documents\project1> poetry install

Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 0 installs, 17 updates, 0 removals

....

(project1-py3.10) PS C:\Users\User\Documents\project1>poetry show -v

Using virtualenv: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\project1-lbkdIgRk-py3.10

....

(project1-py3.10) PS C:\Users\User\Documents\project1>cd C:\User\Documents\prj2

(project1-py3.10) PS C:\User\Documents\prj2>poetry show -v

Using virtualenv: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\project1-lbkdIgRk-py3.10
....

(project1-py3.10) PS C:\User\Documents\prj2> poetry install

Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 0 installs, 16 updates, 0 removals

....

(project1-py3.10) PS C:\User\Documents\prj2>poetry show -v

Using virtualenv: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\project1-lbkdIgRk-py3.10

....

(project1-py3.10) PS C:\User\Documents\prj2>
```

Why the virtual environment not changed to new virtual environment?

Comment: The directory separator on Windows is ``\`` and not `/` as on Linux/Mac as described by the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). Please do not use `/` in file/folder paths, especially not in a batch file. The batch file `run.bat` should have has first line `cd /D "C:\User\Documents\prj2"` or even better `pushd "C:\User\Documents\prj2"` and `popd` as last line. `start.bat` should be with `poetry run python runner.py "C:\User\Documents\run.bat"`.

Comment: The file extension `.bat` is for downwards compatibility with batch files created for `COMMAND.COM` of MS-DOS, Windows 95/98/ME. Batch files designed for being processed by the *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe` should have the file extension `.cmd`. It would be better renaming `run.bat` to `run.cmd`. __CMD__ has the internal [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-command) __START__. No batch file should have ever the name of a Windows command. `start.bat` is better renamed to something like `Prj2Start.cmd`.

Comment: The project is run now with just `Prj2Start.cmd` or `.\Prj2Start.cmd`. Please take a look on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) There is explained with an example in chapter __F)__ that no process can modify the environment variables of an already running process and why this is not possible. Each process can modify only its own set of environment variables or pass its own set or a specific set of environment variables to a new (child) process created by a process.

Comment: I recommend reading first carefully and completely the Microsoft documentation for the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw). This kernel function is called by `cmd.exe` whenever an executable must be run by the *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe` with a null pointer for function parameter `lpCurrentDirectory` except on using the internal command __START__ with its option `/D` for specifying a different current working directory for the process.

Comment: The function parameter `lpEnvironment` is always a null pointer on `CreateProcess` called by `cmd.exe`. Next read the *Python* documentation about the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) which is on Windows a *Python* wrapper module for `CreateProcess` called without or with a [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure. `suprocess.Popen` can be run with a specific list of environment variables for the process like `test` which is hopefully an executable.

Comment: I don't understand the variable name `path_to_bath`. *bath* is not __batch__. `test` is hopefully not a batch file, but an executable file with file extension `.exe` or `.com`. What is `test`? That is not explained anywhere in the question. I don't know what `poetry` is at all. If that is an executable file with name `poetry.exe`, it is highly recommended writing in all batch files `poetry.exe` instead of just `poetry`. That helps other readers like me and helps `cmd.exe` finding the executable a little bit faster with less file system accesses.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
poetry shell
```

this command should activate the venv.

Comment: You want to say that in run.bat need to add poetry shell?

Comment: yes, you can try that, do poetry shell then install, etc.

Comment: https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#shell

Comment: If you need to ask questions before you can give an answer it belongs first as a comment.  Do not speculate on what the author has done or not done.

Comment: yeah, sorry but i couldn't because of my reputation ...

Comment: I make poetry shell
Not working
Spawning shell within C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\prj2-lbkdIgRk-py3.10
But i write command `poetry show -v` to console i get old environment
Using virtualenv: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\project1-lbkdIgRk-py3.10

Comment: okay, maybe you need to cd into the right path already in the start.bat;

Comment: Nevertheless, I would recommend reconsidering the usefulness of having two separate .bat files. Instead, I would recommend activating the venv in the command line with poetry shell and then running the script.

Comment: If it were only 2 bat, I wouldn't be so steamed up. There will be a lot of them)

Answer (score 0):

Solving this problem was add to run.bat
command `call deactivate`